# ASP.NET Core 3.1 + Open ID Connect + AD doesn't persist id token into User.Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I am trying to implement Open Id authentication with our company Azure AD, and for that, we're using the following Microsoft guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp.

While the sample project works well, migrating the same method to our website does not. The user is correctly redirected to the external authentication (Azure AD) after clicking the Sign In button, and after logging in, the external authentication (Azure AD) is redirecting the user back to our website. At this point all looks good, if we inspect the external authentication callback request to our website, we can see the id token was correctly returned in the console logs; however, none of this information seems to have propagated/saved to the `User.Identity` object, which means that if we use `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` in _LoginPartial.cshtml it is always null.

I suspect that since our solution is built under Kentico CMS, Kentico has its own Kentico Authentication Handler and so I'm guessing it's clearing/overriding our open id authentication.

**Is there a way to clear all registered authentication handlers? Or anything workaround on that?**

Sample code below so you can get an idea of our implementation:

Startup.cs:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
    . . .

        services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

        . . .

        services.AddRazorPages()
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
    }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
    . . .

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

    . . .
    }
```

appSettings.json:

```
  . . .

  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "[Enter the domain of your tenant, e.g. contoso.onmicrosoft.com]",
    "ClientId": "Enter_the_Application_Id_here",
    "TenantId": "Enter_the_Tenant   _Id_here",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  }

  . . .
```

_LoginPartial.cshtml

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
    @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        <li class="nav-item">
            <span class="navbar-text text-dark">Hello @User.Identity.Name!</span>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="MicrosoftIdentity" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignOut">Sign out</a>
        </li>
     }
    else
    {
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="MicrosoftIdentity" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignIn">Sign in</a>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what lead to your problem because I can't understand what is 'propagate to User.Identity' and 'check whether the user is authenticated'. In my opinion, after integrating azure ad, we need to use access token and id token to obtain user information. Just like the sample code asked you set the redirect url, the sign in module is independent from your project.

Comment: Hi @Tiny-wa, so the azure ad logging process seems working fine and we even see that the id token is returned, the next step would be checking User.Identity.IsAuthenticated property on login partial page in order to check whether the user is logged or not. So at this point, my expectation would be that this object would have all user information that was returned from the id token, which is not happening, the User.Identity object has no information at all.